# Script to Copy Logic Bricks

Tags: objects

How can I use this script to copy the logic bricks from one object to another?

```
 def copyObject( scene, name, copyobj, loc ):
      bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
      copyobj.select = True
      l = (loc[0] - copyobj.location[0],loc[1] - copyobj.location[1],loc[2] - copyobj.location[2])
      bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move( TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":l} )
      obj = scene.objects[0]
      obj.name = name
      return obj
```

Comment: You can copy logic bricks from one object to another without any script....

Comment: select two object in 3D window + <space> + type "copy logic bricks"

Comment: I liked copying as 'sdfgeoff' taught. Most wanted to learn how to use this script. Could you teach me?